# How do I make a secure HTTPS call from Android

Tags: java, android, apache, ssl, https

When connecting to a HTTPS backend, do the regular HTTP calls from the apache library available in Android produce secure communication?

Because the endpoint is HTTPS, and assuming the backend is secure, is this a valid way to send a password from an Android client? Note that in the code below the password is inserted into the body of the POST request plain and without encryption.

My code is as follows:

```
// Create post 
String url = "https://example.endpoint.com/token";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
HttpResponse response = null;
HttpEntity entity = null;

// Populate the post request            
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("username", user);
json.put("password", pass);
StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString() );
se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
post.setEntity(se);

// Execute the post request
response = client.execute(post);
```

The libraries used are:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost; 
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default settings are mostly secure (that is proper certificate validation). But, at least older versions of the apache HTTP library as available on Android do not support SNI (Server Name Indication) and thus fail to work with server where you have different certificates on the same IP address.

I also doubt that they do proper checks if a certificate was revoked, but in this case they are not far worse then the browsers :(

Comment: If you are in control of the application and all of the servers it should connect to, then certificate pinning is a good thing. But, if the application should be able to communicate with servers you don't control and you never know when they replace their certificate, then pinning will not work.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS uses SSL so yeah it's secure, but don't send the password in every requests (only when it's necessary) and don't store it on the phone.

If you want to improve your security, you can add SSL pinning too: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning